# Django templates: using include to pass a form template; how to write the form?

Tags: django, templates

I simply would like to create a form, throw it in a template, and use the include keyword to include it in my home.html file.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
# forms.py
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)

# views.py
def orderView(request):
    template = 'orders.html'
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = OrderForm()
    else:
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com']
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, 'orders.html', {'form': form})


<!-- templates/orders.html -->
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% form.as_p %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>

<!-- templates/home.html -->
...
<div class="orders">
    {% include 'orders.html' %}
</div>
...
```

Comment: {{ form.as_p }} instead of {% form.as_p %}

Answer (score 0):

Use `{{ form.as_p }}` instead of `{% form.as_p %}`. And render `home.html` from view to make the `include` work. Don't forget to pass the form like below:

`{% include 'orders.html' with form=form %}`

Comment: i changed `{{form.as_p}}` and by render home.html you mean in the render statement of the orderView function above.  if so, I made both changes and still not working